# phpMyAdmin - #1932 Table doesn't exist (collation in use) after reinstalling

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, config

I'm in the middle of doing my thesis when I found my XAMPP server got some error logs, so I decide to reinstall my XAMPP to a newer version (I got this idea from some threads in SO). I moved my `mysql > data` folder and restored it again in my new installation folder.

However when I accessed phpMyAdmin and tried to do some operations in my DB I got this (I've never seen my `collation` column is in use before):
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQrax.png)

P.S. I deleted line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';` from the `config.inc.php` file before accessing my DB since it keep showing error message like this [error message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P95lN.png)

I've run out of idea about how to solve this. Any help appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found my own solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/675445/mysql-innodb-lost-tables-but-files-exist). 
Moving database files is kinda tricky, and supposedly I don't remove any old logfiles since they are important for any further access.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest reinstall or download config.inc.php for default settings

[Check This one](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html)

Comment: delete folder xampp located  in your C:\xampp