# XAMPP phpMyAdmin Session Error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I had two XAMPP installed in my computer. XAMPP1 was in C:\XAMPP and XAMPP2 is in D:\XAMPP. Both were working fine. I needed to delete XAMPP1 (c:\xampp) and deleted. After that My XAMPP2 PHPMyAdmin Stopped Working. It displays error message something like this:

[image]

It is searching SESSION DATA in C:\XAMPP\TMP. So I created empty folder C:\XAMPP\TMP

After that it displays error message like this:

[image]

This means If I Install another xampp in C: drive it will work. But I don't want to install another xampp in C: drive. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you changed your php.ini / httpd.conf at all?

Comment: No. I haven't changed anything. I just removed XAMPP1 (C:\XAMPP) folder

Comment: To which end then - have you restarted your apache instance? If that doesn't work, restart the PC / server as a whole, the old apache process is probably still running

Comment: I have restarted the server multiple times. My New Xampp is running smoothly. Apache is running, MySQL is also running in port 3306 but phpmyadmin is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the installation in D:\XAMPP is not properly configured.

- Adjust `session.save_path` in your `php.ini`. You most likely don't want the session data in the old Xampp directory.
- Also check that `extension_dir` in your `php.ini` matches the correct path to your php extensions. This could be the reason that the `mysqli` extension is not loaded, if it's pointing to a different path.
- Restart Apache and try again
- Check your log files for errors, e.g. failed extension loading etc.
- If the error about the missing `mysqli` extension persists, make sure it is not commented out in your `php.ini`

---

Edit:

Sorry, I don't have the rights to comment yet... :(

Not sure, if remote debugging is very effective here. Search the error message and have a look for example here: [phpMyAdmin - #1932 Table doesn't exist (collation in use) after reinstalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724548/phpmyadmin-1932-table-doesnt-exist-collation-in-use-after-reinstalling)

Comment: Thanks, now phpmyadmin is running but I am getting this screen: http://prntscr.com/jzproi